# Trying to find a way where a discord bot can randomly send a message in a given channel

Tags: discord.js

I'm using the commando framework.  I want the bot I'm making to be able start randomly sending messages in a certain channel when given a command to do so. For example if I typed "!radar"  I would expect the bot to continue to randomly send a predetermined message in that channel until it is told to stop.

Here's the code I attempted to use:

```
   async run(message){
       message.say("Scanning....") 
       while(true){
        var number = 30; 
        var imageNumber = Math.floor (Math.random() * (number - 1 + 1)) + 1;
        if(imageNumber == 1){
            message.say("^ detected!");
        }
    }
}
```

When I attempt this code I don't seem to get any errors logs, but I don't get any response from the bot when I send the command.

Comment: `message#say()` is not a method. I believe you're referring to the `TextChannel#send()` method. Also, please keep in mind what you're currently doing is considered as API abuse, and could result in yourself being banned from using the API and Discord as a whole.

Comment: `message.say( )` is another way of /saying `message.channel.send` or `TextChannel.send()`  using discord.js-commando.

Comment: The bot Im making is private but you're probably right.  I'll rework the idea